# Looking for Modernizr references

Tags: gruntjs, modernizr

I'm trying to use the grunt-modernizr plugin in my project but I'm receiving the following output when I run tasks:

```
Running "modernizr:dist" (modernizr) task

>> Explicitly including these tests:
>> pointerevents

Looking for Modernizr references
```

I'm not receiving any type of error the terminal just goes back to the directory that I'm in, as if it's just giving up.

Here is my grunt file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig ({
    // Do grunt-related things in here
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        modernizr: {
          dist: {
              "dest": "javascripts/modernizr-custom.js",
              "parseFiles": true,
              "customTests": [],
              "devFile": "javascripts/modernizr-custom.js",
              "outputFile": "javascripts/min/modernizr-custom.min.js",
              "tests": [
                  "pointerevents",
                  "css/pointerevents"
              ],
              "extensibility": [
                  "setClasses"
              ],
              "uglify": false
          }
        },

        cssmin: {
          target: {
            files: {
                'css/min/bootstrap.min.css': ['css/bootstrap.css']
            }
          }
        },              
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-modernizr");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['modernizr', 'cssmin']);
};
```

Output from running grunt --verbose:

```
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
Initializing config...OK

Registering "grunt-modernizr" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bootstrap-three-wordpress/wp-content/themes/brandozz/node_modules/grunt-modernizr/package.json...OK
Parsing /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bootstrap-three-wordpress/wp-content/themes/brandozz/node_modules/grunt-modernizr/package.json...OK
Loading "modernizr.js" tasks...OK
+ modernizr

Registering "grunt-contrib-cssmin" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bootstrap-three-wordpress/wp-content/themes/brandozz/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/package.json...OK
Parsing /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bootstrap-three-wordpress/wp-content/themes/brandozz/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/package.json...OK
Loading "cssmin.js" tasks...OK
+ cssmin
Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ default

No tasks specified, running default tasks.
Running tasks: default

Running "default" task

Running "modernizr" task

Running "modernizr:dist" (modernizr) task
Verifying property modernizr.dist exists in config...OK
Files: -> javascripts/modernizr-custom.js
Verifying property modernizr exists in config...OK

>> Explicitly including these tests:
>> pointerevents

Looking for Modernizr references
```

Comment: Have you tried running `grunt` with the `--verbose` flag?

Comment: I added the output from the grunt --verbose above

Answer (score 1):

This is something I just came across too and seems to be `grunt-modernizr` stopping after `customizr` doesn't find any files to crawl (it crawls by default).

If you add `"crawl": false` to your `modernizr:dist` task that should fix the problem.

Also, I think `"extensibility": [ "setClasses" ],` should be `"options": [ "setClasses" ],`.

Comment: Have the same problem but the idea is to let it crawl your code and let it built a modernizr version for your code, no?

Comment: There's two different use cases. In mine I was looking for an automated way of building Modernizr from a set of known tests (based on the grunt build confit from their web based builder) and thus I didn't want it to crawl anything. In the other instance you would need to have `crawl` enabled and a `files : { src : ... }` section with your source files specified.

Comment: Well, I tried the same thing (copied grunt config from online modernizr build) but ... both of them showed this error.

Comment: Based on [this](https://github.com/Modernizr/modernizr-neue/pull/74) the formatting of their build config on the Modernizr build site wasn't actually compatible with grunt-modernizr. Basically `parseFiles` did nothing and should've been `crawl`, the multiple output file options were ignored and should be `dest` only, and if you're trying to parse files you need to explicitly add them using `files : { src : [ '*.css', '*.js' ] }` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

To use the [grunt-modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr) task to crawl your code for `Modernizr` references you'll have to look at the [config properties](https://github.com/Modernizr/customizr#config-file) for the `customizr` task as this is part of `grunt-modernizr` 's node_modules:

```
modernizr: {
    dist: {
        dest: 'bower_components/modernizr/build/modernizr.custom.js',
        uglify: false,
        options: [
            'setClasses',
            'addTest'
        ],
        files: {
            src: ['js/app/**/*.js', 'js/app/*.js']
        }
    }
}
```

**devFile:** doesn't seem to matter where you point at
**dest:** instead of `outputFile`, note I'm just outputting to a build directory that's not part of the package
**uglify:** false if you have other minifying options like bundleconfig.json
**options:** to bypass the default options `{ "setClasses", "addTest", "html5printshiv", "testProp", "fnBind" }`
**files:** to enlist your crawlable director(y|ies), make sure you take care of the root files and/or subdirectories as well

---

Load the required tasks, in my case:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-modernizr');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
```

Refer to the `'modernizr:dist'` task => `grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'modernizr:dist', 'copy']);`

Which results in an unminified 34kb file:

> Running "clean:files" (clean) task
>   19 paths cleaned.
>   Running "modernizr:dist" (modernizr) task
>   Looking for Modernizr references
>   1 match in js/app/classes/yambo.options.js
>   bgpositionxy
>   1 match in js/app/modules/yambo.audio.js
>   audio
>   Ready to build using these settings:
>   setClasses, addTest
>   Building your customized Modernizr...OK
>   Success! Saved file to bower_components/modernizr/build/modernizr.custom.js
>   Process terminated with code 0.
>   Running "copy:main" (copy) task
>   Copied 11 files
>   Done, without errors.

---

This way there's no need to even go to the online build to add a feature test. Simply reference `Modernizr` throughout your js code:

```
window.Yambo = (function($, modernizr, ns){
    ns.Audio = {
        extension: (function () {
            return modernizr && modernizr.audio.mp3
                ? 'mp3'
                : modernizr.audio.ogg
                ? 'ogg'
                : 'wav';
        }())
    };

    return ns;
}(window.jQuery, window.Modernizr, window.Yambo || {}));
```

Make sure to use the [correct property name](https://www.browserleaks.com/modernizr) for a feature detection, so `customizr` can pick it up and provide a test to your custom build.

---

This should be also possible for css but haven't been testing that for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like you missed source files.
>   http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-object-format

Try to include

```
"dist": {
    "files": {
        "src": ['!<%= appDir %>assets/js/bower/modernizr/**']
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have bower installed in my project so that directory currently does not exist.

Comment: ok. if you can download modernizr js and place somewhere on root directory and reference here in this code, may fix your error. Let me know if it's works for you.

Comment: So when I create my modernizr file do I need to do 1. download the build file and 2. download the grunt config? I need both?

Comment: Thanks for your help but my solution for the time being is to download the build and save it to a modernizr.js file and link to it the old fashion way. I've wasted to much time trying to get grunt-modernizr to work so I'm now just using grunt for grunt-contrib-cssmin. I'll experiment with some other plugins and return to this at another time.